# SQL Query - Duplicate data more than once based on values assigned

Tags: mysql

I am trying to duplicate/copy data from "product" table and add new values in "carrier" column.

Example:
In "product" table, I have a list of products which I will need to assign with another table, "carrier". There are currently 5 carriers in "carrier" table.

In "product_carrier" table, I would like to create new entries here. Product "sample-1" is assigned to carrier 1, 2, 3 and 4. Product "sample-2" is assigned to carrier 5.

Thus, it becomes as such:

sample-1 | 1

sample-1 | 2

sample-1 | 3

sample-1 | 4

sample-2 | 5

This is the database structure of the e-commerce system that I am currently using to assign carriers.

My tables are -

ps_product: id_product

ps_carrier: id_carrier

ps_product_carrier: id_product, id_carrier_reference

My hunch is that, I will need to update 2 set of data groups. Firstly, products set to carrier (1, 2, 3, 4) and another set of products to assign to carrier (5). I will run 2 set of queries to achieve this.

I have no clue as to execute a duplicate of a product and create insert multiple values for different carriers. Currently, I have thousands of products that need to be assigned accordingly.

I have no idea if this is possible and that if you have any advice, that will be truly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: how you define the product for carrier 1,2,3,4 and the product for carrier 5????

Comment: I was thinking to list down all the product that is assigned to carrier 5 then run an SQL with... example WHERE id_product !=...

Comment: So `product_carrier` is empty and now you want to create records. E.g.: There are 6000 products in the database. 3000 products must be combined with carriers 1 to 4 and the other 3000 products must be combined with carrier 5. And there is nothing in the database to tell us to which of the two groups a product belongs. Is this correct?

Comment: Can you put your current table `desc` and your expect result?

Comment: Yes you are right, @Thorsten Kettner ... Because data will only be inserted into product_carrier when we update via frontend. Unfortunately, it does not offer bulk update. Thus, the query here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a table named  table_with_product_list (or a list) when you assign all the product you want assign to a carrier

you can use a insert select

eg for multiple carrier (1,2,3,4)

```
insert into ps_product_reference (id_product, id_carrier_reference)
select table_with_product_list.product_id, t.id_carrier
from table_with_product_list
cross join (
    select id_carrier from ps_carrier
    where id_carrier in  ( 1,2,3,4)

)  t
```

for single carrier (5)

```
insert into ps_product_reference (id_product, id_carrier_reference)
select table_with_product_list.product_id ,  5
from table_with_product_list
```

Comment: Are you inner joining table_with_product_list with carrier? I do not have the same key to join these 2 tables. I will also need to have a WHERE clause because there are 2 set of data groups with different carriers, right?

Comment: @Enthu  thanks  .. wrong join  (wrong query)..... answer  update with cross join for multiple carrier

Comment: I have updated my question with related tables. I have execute the query you have created but currently, it is returning an error. #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias. insert into ps_product_carrier (p.id_product, t.id_carrier)
select p.id_product
from ps_product p
cross join (
    select t.id_carrier from ps_carrier t
    where t.id_carrier in (1,2,3,4)
)

Comment: insert into ps_product_carrier (id_product, id_carrier_reference)
select ps_product.id_product, t.id_carrier
from ps_product
cross join (
    select id_carrier from ps_carrier
    where id_carrier in (1,2,3,4)

)  t . It is working perfectly. Can I just add, if I want to add a WHERE clause to insert the products that I do not want to add carriers (1,2,3,4), I am able to add after the t, right? Cos these are 2 set of different carriers to assign.

Comment: Yes yuo can reduce the result of the select using a where condition after  the table (t) name

Answer (score 0):

As there is nothing in the database to indicate whether a product shall be combined with carriers 1 to 4 or with carrier 5, you'll have to state them yourself. In my opinion there is nothing that speaks against two separate `INSERT` statements. You can use a text editor or Excel maybe or a programm you quickly write yourself to build the `VALUES` clause:

```
insert into ps_product_carrier (id_product, id_carrier_reference)
values 
  (1111, 1),
  (1111, 2),
  (1111, 3),
  (1111, 4),
  (3333, 1),
  (3333, 2),
  (3333, 3),
  (2222, 4),
  ... ;

commit;

insert into ps_product_carrier (id_product, id_carrier_reference)
values 
  (2222, 5),
  (4444, 5),
  ... ;

commit;
```

Or start with the second statement above and then instead of the first query use:

```
insert into ps_product_carrier (id_product, id_carrier_reference)
select p.id_product, c.id_carrier
from ps_product p
cross join (select id_carrier from ps_carrier where id_carrier in (1,2,3,4)) c
where p.id_product not in 
  (select id_product from ps_product_carrier where id_carrier_reference = 5);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the previous answer works just fine but I am sure your solution will benefit us too. Much appreciated. :)